# Can't Debug app in android studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

Im trying to debug a very simple app i wrote from the Udacity course.
when i run the app in debug mode the app launches on the device, Debugger connects as said in line 1, the message
"waiting for debugger" is shown on my phone for a second. But when that message is gone from phone the debugger is automatically disconnected (line 2).

```
1. Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8604', transport: 'socket'
2. Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8604', transport: 'socket'
```

I read other question people had here with this issue.
tried rebooting AS, my device, killing adb server and closing Bluestacks.
The only way i managed to debug apps is by pressing Attach debugger to android proccess while i manually opened the app from my phone.
Any ideas? i really need debug option to work properly.

EDIT: When i run the app in normal state i get this log:
7-07 19:57:06.253  22333-22390/com.example.android.justjava I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-07 19:57:06.258  22333-22390/com.example.android.justjava D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0

Why debug mode is in 0?

Comment: Did you try built-in emulator or Genymotion?

Comment: USB Debugging actived in Developer Options?

Comment: @N1to Yes, its working with bluestacks. Perhaps the problem is with my phone/ app in my phone?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly an answer, since I never understood why it happened, but the same thing happened to me and I resolved it by restarting both my computer and my device, and it has not recurred since. Believe it or not I put up with this for almost a week before it occurred to me to restart my device.

Comment: unfortunately, iv'e tried this but still had issues.